# How to process concurrent requests sequentially coming from certain user to specific endpoint

Tags: go, concurrency

I am having trouble with handling concurrent requests coming from user to specific endpoint. The problem I am encountering is when user makes a request to certain endpoint with a certain parameter, to be specific with uuid, I pass that parameter to stored procedure then query the database and db returns error since first transaction is not complete. I want subsequent requests wait until previous processed if request is coming from the same user and to specific endpoint. How do I do that?

I tried to implement it using mutexes but it seemed didn't work.
I want to solve this problem only in server side without touching database.

Comment: Do you use the same connection to handle the second request that you used to start the transaction? You should start a new one.

Comment: You can probably use [`golang.org/x/sync/singleflight`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/singleflight?tab=doc)

Comment: @BurakSerdar why is that?

Comment: Transactions, and in general database operations are sequential. Concurrent requests must come through different connections. If you have multiple goroutines handling requests, they should start their own connections and close it when they're done.

Comment: @JimB Thank you, it seems it's working but should I call `.Forget` every time I call a function cause it seems that if don't call `.Forget` program will eventually end up  running out of memory?

Comment: @thisismamatto: `Forget` is to ignore outstanding calls and start new ones. If they returned, there's nothing to forget